# How to set background color of NSWindowController on loading?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to set background color of a NSWindowController on windowDidLoad like this:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];


    [self.window setBackgroundColor: NSColor.whiteColor];
    [[self.window contentView] setNeedsDisplay:YES];

  }
```

However, it is not working and the color of NSWindowController is not changing.

Any help is heartily appreciated. Many Many thanks in advance.

Comment: does this method get called?

Comment: @Astoria yes and i have tried the code on awake from nib but no benefit.

Comment: What in the world NSView for?

Comment: @ElTomato will i have to put a ns view as a background?

Comment: Every window has a view (NSView).  Just create an NSView subclass and set that to your window's view class.

Comment: @EL TOMATO good suggestion sir, however could you also tell me why is not my code working?

Comment: I don't find setBackgroundColor if I look up the API document for NSWindow.  Do you?

Comment: @ElTomato nope but it's there in auto complete. :) also, i had found it on stack over for

Comment: I wouldn't use that method unless I subclassed NSWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy solution

1. Go to NSWindow  **Identity Inspector**
2. Add a key into **User defined runtime attributes** with key name *backgroundColor* of type **Color** and give it a color value like shown in given below screen shot.
   [image]